# What command should I use to launch a jar file from the context menu using Windows registry?

Tags: java, command, registry, contextmenu

I am currently trying to make a jar file launch from a right click on a folder's background.

I have found the context menu launch (can't remember where, but essentially add to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell` as new key and then add a command key in that with the action to do on click).

And the item location being %1 on this similar question on superuser: `https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu`

But I am stuck on the code for the action of launching the program and passing it the directory.

My most recent attempt is this: `java -jar "fullpath\program.jar" "%1"`

java -jar to run it, path for the location, %1 to hopefully pass the directory path.

I've tried a bunch of variants of this too but can't get it working. Any ideas?

### EDIT: What I did in the end.

I created a bat file and wrote in it:

```
start javaw "%~dp0/program.jar" "%cd%"
```

This runs the java file and sends it the users working directory. `start javaw` is used instead of just `java` to make the command line close after launching the java program. `%~dp0` gets the bat file's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"%1"` part will not work with directory background, but the program is started having that directory as working directory. (Windows 7 is giving an error if '"%1"' is in the command.)

Use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

to get it.

If you can't change the code, write a * wrapper* that gets this directory and calls the `main` method of the original class passing that directory as argument (or write a shell script to do that and invokes java with the argument)